# why isn't my async function working properly?

Tags: javascript, async-await, jspdf

I have an async function which draws an image in my pdf:

```
const doc = new jsPDF();
var base = "";
async function setimage(){
   base = await loadheaderImageAsURL("/logo.png");    
   doc.setFillColor(128, 29, 5);
   doc.rect(167,43,33,10,'F');
   doc.setFillColor(4, 141, 196);
   doc.rect(167,60,33,10,'F');
   doc.addImage(base,'PNG',168,45,50,50);
}

document.getElementById('generate').addEventListener('click',async function(){

     setimage(); //doesn't work
     var base_1 = await loadheaderImageAsURL("/logo1.png");
     doc.addImage(base_1,'PNG',168,45,50,50); // this works
     doc.save("report.pdf");
})
```

The function isn't working. How do I fix this?

Comment: You're not awaiting the function.

Comment: because `setimage` is also async and needs to be awaited `await  setimage();`

Comment: yes `loadheaderImageAsURL` returns a promise

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @bill.gates, setting `await setimage();` works, as the function executes only after getting a promise